# Outdoor exhaust pipes from my heating system

Tags: outdoor, exhaust

What happens if snow covers my outdoor exhaust pipes from my heating system in the winter?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What do you think will happen?

Answer (score 1):

*Scenario 1*: Nothing. The heated exhaust air will melt its way through the snow and you won't have a problem.

*Scenario 2*: The furnace will malfunction. The exhaust pressure sensor will trip, causing an incomplete startup cycle.

*Scenario 3*: You'll get poisonous exhaust gases accumulating in your home, possibly causing illness or death.

*Moral of the story*: Make sure that doesn't happen by extending the pipes or whatever else is necessary. Make sure you understand how to do it properly so you don't make the problem worse.

Answer (score 1):

Under ideal circumstances the warm exhaust will melt the snow as it falls. The less than ideal circumstances could include but not limited to. You have a very energy efficient home. The heating system starts so infrequently that falling snow clogs the vent. The power to your home fails while snow is falling then returns while you are sleeping. The heating system restarts with the vent clogged. A drift of snow slides off your roof and clogs the vent. Any of these cases could result in a build up of carbon monoxide gas in your home. Some localities have increased the minimum height above grade for vents after some high profile deaths of entire families. As carbon dioxide is  deadly, odorless and tasteless, invest in a carbon monoxide detector for each level of your home